Casting method asTextItem throws error for Google form item
This code is to make sure that the item can be operated as correct type in Google form. This code throws TypeError: item.asTextItem is not a function at the line return item.asTextItem();. It seems to me that you can ONLY go into that line by being the correct item type. What could be the problem or solution?
function createFormItem_(form, itemData, config, indices, questionCount) {
  const itemHandlers = {
    'Single': createSingleChoiceItem_,
    'Multiple': createMultipleChoiceItem_,
    'ShortAnswer': createShortAnswerItem_,
    'DateOnly': createDateItem_
  };

  // Get the base type (handle Multiple variants)
  const baseType = itemData[indices.itemType].split(/\d+/)[0];
  const handler = itemHandlers[baseType] || createDefaultItem_;
  const item = handler(form, itemData, config, indices);
  
  return item;
}

function createShortAnswerItem_(form, itemData, config, indices) {
  const item = form.addTextItem();
  const validationType = itemData[indices.validationCol];
  
  const validations = {
    'Email': createEmailValidation_,
    'PhoneNumber': createPhoneValidation_
  };
  
  if (validationType in validations) {
    const validation = validations[validationType]();
    item.setValidation(validation);
  }
  
  return item;
}
function updateQuestionItem_(form, config, row, cols, existingStructureArr, questionCount, position) {
  const itemId = row[cols.id];
  const oldItemIndex = existingStructureArr.indexOf(itemId);
  
  let item;
  if (oldItemIndex >= 0) {
    const oldTitle = existingStructureArr[oldItemIndex + 1]; //String stored as ID1;Title1;ID2;Title2 => TitleIndex == IdIndex + 1
    item = GetQuestionItemInFormByTitle_(oldTitle, form);
    form.moveItem(item, position - 1);
    
    isChoiceQuestion = item.getType() == FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE || item.getType() == FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX;
    if(isChoiceQuestion) applyChoices_(item, row, cols, config);
  } else {
    item = createFormItem_(form, row, config, cols, questionCount)
  }

  applyCommonProperties_(item, row, cols, questionCount);
  return item;
}


function applyCommonProperties_(item, itemData, indices, questionCount) {
  const title = isNumbered ? 
    `${questionCount}. ${itemData[indices.questionCol]}` : 
    itemData[indices.questionCol];

  item = ConvertGeneric2SpecificItem_(item);
  item.setTitle(title)
      .setRequired(itemData[indices.requiredCol])
      .setHelpText(itemData[indices.itemGuide]);
}

function ConvertGeneric2SpecificItem_(item) {
  try {
    switch (item.getType()) {
      case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
        return item.asMultipleChoiceItem();
      case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
        return item.asCheckboxItem();
      case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
        return item.asListItem();
      case FormApp.ItemType.TEXT:
        return item.asTextItem(); //<= Error here
      case FormApp.ItemType.PARAGRAPH_TEXT:
        return item.asParagraphTextItem();
      case FormApp.ItemType.DATE:
        return item.asDateItem();
      case FormApp.ItemType.TIME:
        return item.asTimeItem();
      // Add more cases for other item types as needed
      default:
        Logger.log(`Invalid item type: ${item.getType()}`);
        return null;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(`Error converting item: ${error.message}`);
    return null;
  }
}


Please provide an example of how you are calling the function

Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

I edited the question with more codes. The error happen one the case of creating new multiple choice item

Could you add console.log(item.getType());console.log(item.getType() ===FormApp.ItemType.TEXT ) before return item.asTextItem();

@TheMaster did and done. It logged TEXT

@TamLe have you tried changing case FormApp.ItemType.TEXT: to case  "TEXT":?

@TamLe 1. What about the second log? Did it log false? 2. Did it throw an error after that in return item.asTextItem()?

@LimeHusky I tried. The code jumped over the case. case 'TEXT':         return item.asTextItem();       case FormApp.ItemType.TEXT:         return item.asTextItem(); <= //still error here

@TheMaster: the item.getType() === FormApp.ItemType.TEXT logged as true :(. It was placed just before return item.asTextItem();

Just to be clear, after it logged true, the next line threw a error. Correct?

@TheMaster: Yes, logged true then throw error.

Even though it is in a try... catch block? It is still unclear how this item is created. Does handler implement a proxy by any chance? What type of item is created? Short answer?

@TheMaster It was a short answer. I included the code of creating the item as the second function.
I add logger of item.getId(), and item.getType() before the switch. They all show proper values.

@TamLe If your question is resolved please put it as an answer so that other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

@LimeHusky I will post something, not even sure what it is, an answer, solution, resolution or work around.

Here is my "answer" for the "bug" encountered at the question. The purpose of the method was to make sure it's the correct ItemType before the code does anything with it.
I spent a lot of time tracking each item/variable line by line to see what happens to them but found nothing wrong. (The debugging in App Script is terrible). I came to the conclusion that Google actually does NOT give the method to cast the specific item type as that same type for some item types (for me specifically MULTIPLE_CHOICE and TEXT). So my "solution" was ignoring the error and move on using the original item. And it works fine as of 31 Oct 24. This is the method.
function ConvertGeneric2SpecificItem_(item)
{
  try
  {
    switch(item.getType())
    {
      case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
        return item.asMultipleChoiceItem();
      case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
        return item.asCheckboxItem();
      case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
        return item.asListItem();
      case FormApp.ItemType.TEXT:
        return item.asTextItem();
      case FormApp.ItemType.PARAGRAPH_TEXT:
        return item.asParagraphTextItem();
      case FormApp.ItemType.DATE:
        return item.asDateItem();
      case FormApp.ItemType.TIME:
        return item.asTimeItem();
      // Add more cases for other item types as needed
      default:
        Logger.log("Invalid item type. Return original item.");
        return item;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(`Error converting item: ${error.message}. Return original item`);
    return item;
  }
}

